# malloc: shmatch.c:115: assertion botched free: start and end chunk sizes differ Aborting...ABORT instruction (core dumped) in bash regex

Tags: regex, bash, malloc, hp-ux

I am trying to evaluate the following regex in bash,

```
[[ build: =~ ^([[:space:]]*build) ]]
```

This line is throwing error as,

```
malloc: shmatch.c:115: assertion botched
free: start and end chunk sizes differ
Aborting...ABORT instruction (core dumped)
```

Is there any fix for this?

The entire code snippet is

```
 echo $line : $val;
 if [[ "$line" =~ ^([[:space:]]*build) ]]
     then
            build=$val
 fi
```

this is the code snippet, basically there are 2 variables **line** and **val** I wanted to assign value of **$val** to variable **build** if the **$line** starts with "build".
e.g.
if **$line** is "build=20" and **$val** is "35"
then I want value of **$build** equal to 35.

I am using HP-UX 11.31 if this is relevant..

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts. Please post samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: A failing assertion is pretty always a bug in bash. BTW, it works fine in my bash (version 4.4.12). Could even be a bug particular to the HP-UX bash port.

Comment: @user1934428, ohh ok..
Will check that..